# How to Save gridview values inside inner repeater by onclick in button(grid footer) ? values only that particular grid only?

Tags: asp.net

[Click to see that design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbTCh.png) I need to save on that particular grid values inside inner repeater when I click to save button (inside footer in gridview)

```
protected void btnAthsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    var documentId = btn.CommandArgument;

    //Get the Repeater Item reference
    //RepeaterItem item = btn.NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;
    //GridView grdScopeofwork = (GridView)item.FindControl("grdScopeofwork");
    if (rptrMain.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rptrMain.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            Repeater rptrscope = (Repeater)rptrMain.Items[i].FindControl("rptrscope");
            foreach (RepeaterItem repItem in rptrscope.Items)
            {
                GridView grdScopeofwork = (GridView)repItem.FindControl("grdScopeofwork");
                ScopeoftheProjectBOL objBOL = new ScopeoftheProjectBOL();
                var fv = grdScopeofwork.FooterRow;
               // Button btnsave = ((Button)fv.FindControl("btnsave"));
                Button btnsave = fv.Controls[fv.Controls.Count - 1].FindControl("btnsave") as Button;

                if (btnsave.CommandName == "ADD")
                {
                    foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in grdScopeofwork.Rows)
                    {
                        objBOL.ItemID = Util.ToInt(((Label)gvRow.FindControl("lblID")).Text);
                        objBOL.ItemCode = ((Label)gvRow.FindControl("lblitem")).Text; ;
                        objBOL.ProjectID = Util.ToInt(((Label)gvRow.FindControl("lblPJID")).Text);
                        objBOL.SCID = Util.ToInt(((Label)gvRow.FindControl("lblSCID")).Text);
                        objBOL.PCID = Util.ToInt(((Label)gvRow.FindControl("lblPCID")).Text);
                        objBOL.Qty = Util.ToDecimal(((Label)gvRow.FindControl("lblqty")).Text);
                        objBOL.PricePerUnit = Util.ToDecimal(((Label)gvRow.FindControl("lblRPU")).Text);
                        DropDownList ddlath = ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("ddlauthor"));
                        objBOL.Authorization = ddlath.SelectedValue;
                        objBOL.Status = "Y";
                        new ScopeoftheProjectBAL().SaveScopeWorkItems(objBOL);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[from that image I need to save only PRJ0006-PRD0003-PRD0003 & PRJ0006-PRD0003-PRD0004 items Details only .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbTCh.png)

Answer (score 0):

i solved the issue...

protected void btnAthsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow gvRow1 = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
        GridView Grid = (GridView)gvRow1.NamingContainer;
        RepeaterItem item = Grid.NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;
        Repeater rptchild = (Repeater)item.NamingContainer;
        RepeaterItem mainitem = rptchild.NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;
        Repeater main = (Repeater)mainitem.NamingContainer;
        Label rowindex = ((Label)mainitem.FindControl("lblrowindex"));
        Label rowindexC = ((Label)item.FindControl("lblrowindexC"));

```
    if (rptrMain.Items.Count > 0)
    {

       // for (int i = 0; i < rptrMain.Items.Count; i++)
        //{
            Repeater rptrscope = (Repeater)rptrMain.Items[Util.ToInt( rowindex.Text)].FindControl("rptrscope");
          //  foreach (RepeaterItem repItem in rptrscope.Items)
          //  {


            GridView grdScopeofwork = (GridView)rptrscope.Items[Util.ToInt("rowindexC")].FindControl("grdScopeofwork");
                ScopeoftheProjectBOL objBOL = new ScopeoftheProjectBOL();
                GridViewRow fv = grdScopeofwork.FooterRow;
                Button btnsave = ((Button)fv.FindControl("btnsave"));



                if (btnsave.CommandName == "ADD")
                {
                    foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in grdScopeofwork.Rows)
                    {


                        objBOL.ItemID = Util.ToInt(((Label)gvRow.FindControl("lblID")).Text);
                        objBOL.ItemCode = ((Label)gvRow.FindControl("lblitem")).Text; ;
                        objBOL.ProjectID = Util.ToInt(((Label)gvRow.FindControl("lblPJID")).Text);
                        objBOL.SCID = Util.ToInt(((Label)gvRow.FindControl("lblSCID")).Text);
                        objBOL.PCID = Util.ToInt(((Label)gvRow.FindControl("lblPCID")).Text);
                        objBOL.Qty = Util.ToDecimal(((Label)gvRow.FindControl("lblqty")).Text);
                        objBOL.PricePerUnit = Util.ToDecimal(((Label)gvRow.FindControl("lblRPU")).Text);
                        DropDownList ddlath = ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("ddlauthor"));
                        objBOL.Authorization = ddlath.SelectedValue;
                        objBOL.Status = "Y";
                        new ScopeoftheProjectBAL().SaveScopeWorkItems(objBOL);

                    }
                }
           // }
      // }
    }

}
```

Add two labels inside the repeters,

```
                               <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblrowindex" Visible="false" Text='<%# Container.ItemIndex %>'></asp:Label>
```